# How to modify the purpose of the KeyPair in the Android.KeyStore

Tags: java, android-keystore, ecdh

When generate a KeyPair in Android.KeyStore, we will set KeyProperties like KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN.
Now, I generate a KeyPair on secp256r1 curve in plaintext. then save it to KeyStore, it can be used to sign or verify signatures, but not to derive keys, I think it may be missing KeyProperties.PURPOSE_AGREE_KEY attribute. How can I add this property for this KeyPair in keystore?

This is my code when I save the KeyPair into KeyStore. PublicKey and PrivateKey generated on secp256r1 curve.

```
public static boolean saveKeyPair(PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey, String alias) {
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null, null);

        byte[] cert = new CertificateManager.CertificateBuilder()
                    .setBasicConstraints(false)
                    .setkeyUsage(0)
                    .setPk(publicKey)
                    .addIssuer(BCStyle.CN, "KeyPair Save For Test")
                    .addSubject(BCStyle.CN, "KeyPair Save For Test")
                    .build(privateKey);

        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
        chain[0] = CertificateManager.createCert(cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, null, chain);

        PublicKey pk = ks.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
        if (ByteUtils.toHexString(pk.getEncoded()).equalsIgnoreCase(ByteUtils.toHexString(publicKey.getEncoded()))) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my code to generate the derived key with ECDH

```
public static byte[] ecdh(String alias, PublicKey ePublicKey) {
    byte[] ret;
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null,null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)ks.getEntry(alias, null);
        PrivateKey privateKey = entry.getPrivateKey();
        KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH","AndroidKeyStore");
        keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
        keyAgreement.doPhase(ePublicKey, true);
        ret = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
        
        return ret;
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

The following is the error when the code runs

```
W/le.activitytes: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLProvider;-><init>()V (unsupported,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/le.activitytes: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLRandom;-><init>()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:130)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.java:228)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.java:96)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:498)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:470)
```

This is my code to generate the KeyPair, for the plaintext generation I didn't use the KeyStore

```
public static KeyPair genKeyPair(){
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
        generator.initialize(spec);
        generator.initialize(256);
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    throw new RuntimeExcepetion(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Android 13(API 33)
use KeyStore.SetEntry to Import KeyPair:

```
val privateKeyEntry = PrivateKeyEntry(privateKey, certificateChain)

ks.setEntry(alias, privateKeyEntry, KeyProtection.Builder(
           KeyProperties.PURPOSE_AGREE_KEY or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
          .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
          .build())
```